# Change Git repository location out of the root directory of Visual Studio 2015 solution

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, directory

I have a Visual Studio solution in [`D:\works\CobraSin`], where Git puts his files as well.
But I need that these files were located in another directory [`C:\MainDocs...`], where I have an automatic backup that manage this type of security service.

How can I set a new local repository to Git for this solution?

Is there a page on VS Tools\Options... menu where we can attribute this?
What I need to command to achieve this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply move your files from `D:\works\CobraSin` to your destination, and reload your project from there.

You can start, instead of copying/moving, by cloning your repo.

```
git clone D:\works\CobraSin C:\MainDocs\aNewFolder
```